# Is there a way in JavaScript to change Enter to Shift + Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is what I tried and obviously failed:

```
ed.on('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
        e.shiftKey = true;
        e.keyCode = 13;
        $(this).trigger(e);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey){
        e.shiftKey = false;
        e.keyCode = 13;
        $(this).trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do this cause based on what I seen I think I'm on the right track and most likely just not triggering it early or something similar.

Additionally, I tried using 'keypress' instead and had no luck with that.

Comment: Even if that worked, wouldn't that just be an infinite loop, as the shiftKey calls !shiftKey, which calls shiftKey, which calls !shiftKey...

Comment: `shiftKey` is a read-only property, so it cannot be changed:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey

Comment: Don't do that. Just a) `preventDefault` and insert a linebreak at the cursor position or (better and easier) b) just use a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When enter is pressed without shift, trigger keydown with enter and shift!

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {
      keyCode: 13, // ENTER
      shiftKey: true
    }));
  } else if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
    console.log('shift + enter');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Comment: Doesnt Work :(.
This part of code doesnt work.
'$(this).trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {
      keyCode: 13, // ENTER
      shiftKey: true
    }));'

Trigger event is not triggering.

Comment: The solution I posted works in all the browsers I have installed on my computer, so I can't quite help you. Could you show how you implemented it in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 6):

```js
document.onkeydown = function onkeydown(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey==false) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        document.execCommand("insertLineBreak");    
    } 
}
```